# Laravel - Passing Model rows count to nav menu that is being used in multiple pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

how can I pass model row counts to  nav menu that is being used by multiple pages.

e.g:

I have a "Posts","Tags" in my navbar but then I would like to display the total number of posts in the table beside the title and this navbar is being used in various pages.

Is there a right way to do this, so I dont have to repeat the query "Post::count()","Tag::count()" all the time and passing it to every controller that is going to be needing the navbar partial? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different ways for this.

The simpler is calling `Post::count()` and `Tag::count()` directly in your view. This seems obvious, but it works really great! If you need these counts every time in this view, this can be a good solution.

The other one I can think of is [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers). You can define that in the routes file or anywhere you think it's relevant. You can use it like that:

```
View::composer('your.view.name', function($view)
{
    $view->with('counts', [
        'posts' => Post::count(),
        'tags'  => Tag::count(),
    ]);
});
```

And then in you view you can use it directly like that `{{ $counts['posts'] }}`

The Laravel way to use [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers) is to declare a service provider that will load the class that will handle you data.

It's cleaner but longer to write, your choice.

As [RDelorier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591795/laravel-passing-model-row-counts-to-nav-menu-that-is-being-used-in-multiple-pa/33592173?noredirect=1#comment54959776_33592173) pointed out, You can then cache your data with view composer so you don't have to query those data anytime you load the page.

You can implement it like this:

```
View::composer('your.view.name', function($view)
{
    //There you can store the number of minutes you want to store the item
    $minutes = 30;

    $view->with('counts', Cache::remember('counts', $minutes, function() {
        return [
            'posts' => Post::count(),
            'tags'  => Tag::count(),
        ];
    }));
});
```

Comment: The good think about using the composer is it will make it easier to use some caching mechanism an not make the same queries every time a view is rendered

Comment: Never thought of that, nice one! I've added it to the response ;)

Comment: Thanks, that's what exactly i'm looking for, right. view composer. But haven't tried that caching thing. How would I implement that in view composer.

Comment: If it answered don't forget to upvote and mark as complete ;) I'll update my post to include one possible implementation of caching

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot :). So no more some cache calling to modify in views? just the 'counts'?

Comment: Not sure I get what you've meant, in the view you only have to call $counts['posts'] or $counts['tags'], that's all. All the sharing/caching stuff is handled inside the View composer